# Why I need to Create quality.point record with type Register Consumed Material to consume non tracking product from Tablet view? OdooV13

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I have a Manufacturing order with routing.

I kept all my row material is non tracking.

If I don't create quality point record(with test type = Register Consumed Materials, using steps from routing) non tracking row material is not visible on tablet view but it will consumed directly when Manufacturing is finished based on bom configuration.

Same behavior is for Byproduct I need to create quality point record (with Test type= Register Byproducts) to have it on tablet view otherwise system will create Byproduct based on bom configuration.

What is reason to have this configuration and not directly visible on tablet view ? Is there any other configuration  is available that i am missing ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a functional question and has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: In previous version non tracking products were coming on tablet view directly, I mean user can consume it more or less because user can see it while consumption, but in new version what is the reason or I am missing any configuration that is not allowing me to have non tracking products directly on tablet view (why to create quality point to have it in tablet view)?